# Xamarin Forms NavigationPage is not but if statement says it is not null

Tags: xamarin, null, comparison

In short, I'm attempting to work out whether the NavigationPage is null or not, but I'm getting a weird issue.

```
if (!ReferenceEquals(navigationPage, null))
{
     await navigationPage.PushAsync(page);
}
```

(It was navigationPage != null) I changed it to this to see if this might help but no such luck. Essentially, every time I load a new page via my HomePage, navigationPage is equal to null in the debugger, however when I run an if on it and say if it's not equal to null disregarding the debugger saying it's null the if statement returns false saying it is not null. After I load a page 2 times (doesn't matter the page) the third time the app crashes saying "Object null reference when it tries to do navigationPage.PushAsync. I've checked this and I believe it's because navigationPage is null.

I have no idea how it is saying something is not null when the debugger says it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Generally one would use

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
```

and Xamarin.Forms will find the instance of the `NavigationPage` that the current page is using, so not sure why you are using an instance of a `NavigationPage` (navigationPage) rather than using the recommended method as outlined in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical).

But I cannot say, without you sharing more of the code you are using, ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), why your `navigationPage` instance gets nulled out.